# Receiving ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(_AppModule)[config -> config].... Over installing Angular-Markdown-Editor

Tags: angular, text-editor

I have installed an Angular project using this command  `ng new --no-standalone  my-text-editor` and I have followed the instructions on this link [Angular Text Editor](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-markdown-editor), after all the steps and running `ng-serve` I kept getting the error as shown in the picture.
[Error shown in the "Console" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S0ZP.png)

Here is my code for the file app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularMarkdownEditorModule } from 'angular-markdown-editor';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularMarkdownEditorModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I tried solving this by creating a config file and adding to the providers but still nothing solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the [angular-markdown-editor](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-markdown-editor?tab=readme-ov-file#import-module) repo, You can do something like this using `forRoot`:

```
AngularMarkdownEditorModule.forRoot({ iconlibrary: 'fa' })
```